# Entity framework fetching error. Wont get referenced objects

Tags: c#, database, entity

Both tables contain information but somehow the database dont give me the MethodComponent object. When I test with:

```
var item = d.Get_Categories();
string name = item.Last().MethodComponent.Last().Name;
```

I get `System.ObjectDisposedException`. Any Idea what's going on?

The model class:

```
    public partial class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.MethodComponent = new HashSet<MethodComponent>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<MethodComponent> MethodComponent { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Database Category:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Category] (
[Id]   INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name] NCHAR (10) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
```

);

Database Component

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MethodComponent] (
[Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[StartDate]  DATETIME       NULL,
[EndDate]    DATETIME       NULL,
[ProjectID]  INT            NULL,
[CategoryID] INT            NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_MethodComponent_Category] FOREIGN KEY ([CategoryID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Category] ([Id]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_MethodComponent_project] FOREIGN KEY ([ProjectID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Project] ([Id])
```

);

Getting data from database:

```
        public List<Category> Get_Categories()
    {

            using (var context = new ProcessDatabaseEntities())
            {
                return context.Category.ToList();

            }

    }
```

EDIT: I added LazyLoadingEnabled = false and now I get another error: System.InvalidOperationException

```
    public List<Category> Get_Categories()
    {

            using (var context = new ProcessDatabaseEntities())
            {
                **context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;**
                return context.Category.ToList();   
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it:

```
        public List<Category> Get_Categories()
    {

            using (var context = new ProcessDatabaseEntities())
            {


                //context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
                var list = context.Category.Include(p => p.MethodComponent).ToList();

                return list;
            }

    }
```